# Create multiple percentage columns based on existing columns in R

Tags: r, data.table

I want to create multiple columns that will show the percentage of each element of `col2`, `col3` and `Total`. The code I came up with only `paste` the percentage in those columns instead of pasting it in new columns.
I have searched on stack and google but I have not found the answer I was looking for.

Sample data :

```
data <- data.table(col1= c("A", "B", "C"),
                   col2= c(43,23,19),
                   col3= c(102,230,149))
data <- data[, Total := col2 + col3]
data <- janitor::adorn_title(data)

Output :

  col1 col2 col3 Total
    A   43  102   145
    B   23  230   253
    C   19  149   168
Total   85  481   566
```

My percentage function :

```
add_percent <- function(dt, col_no_percent, col_percent){
  dt <- dt[
    , c(.SD[, col_no_percent, with=FALSE],
        lapply(.SD[, col_percent, with=FALSE], function(x){
          paste0(x, format(round(x / sum(x) * 100 * 2, 1), nsmall = 1, decimal.mark = "."))

        }))
    ]
}
```

Data output with my function:

```
data <- add_percent(data, "col1", c("col2", "col3", "Total"))
    col1    col2     col3    Total
       A 43 50.6 102 21.2 145 25.6
       B 23 27.1 230 47.8 253 44.7
       C 19 22.4 149 31.0 168 29.7
   Total 85 100.0 481 100.0 566 100.0
```

Data output I want :

```
  col1 col2 col3 Total col2.x col3.x Total.x
    A   43  102   145   50.6   21.2   25.6
    B   23  230   253   27.1   47.8   44.7
    C   19  149   168   22.4   31.0   29.7
Total   85  481   566  100.0  100.0  100.0
```

It is possible that my data will contain way more columns, so all the new columns will have to be created "automatically". So I would like to know how to generate those columns based on my percent function or even a more efficient way if possible.

Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Initial Data. Note I removed the janitor step. Will do that part at the end.

```
data <- data.table(col1= c("A", "B", "C"),
                   col2= c(43,23,19),
                   col3= c(102,230,149))
data <- data[, Total := col2 + col3]
```

Add percent columns for all numeric columns and add "Total" row

```
cols <- names(data)[sapply(data, is.numeric)]

data[, paste0(cols, '_pct') := lapply(.SD, function(x) 100*x/sum(x))
   , .SDcols = cols]


adorn_totals(data)
 #  col1 col2 col3 Total  col2_pct  col3_pct Total_pct
 #     A   43  102   145  50.58824  21.20582  25.61837
 #     B   23  230   253  27.05882  47.81705  44.69965
 #     C   19  149   168  22.35294  30.97713  29.68198
 # Total   85  481   566 100.00000 100.00000 100.00000
```

Comment: Wonderful! As usual a great answer @IceCreamToucan.

Answer (score 1):

I know it is a data.table question, but dplyr has a really nice way of doing this. So just to add it as one possible answer.

```
library(dplyr)

# this is your function (slightly changed)
as_perc <- function(x) {

  paste0(format(100 * (round(x/ sum(x),  2)), nsmall = 1, decimal.mark = "."), "%")

}

data %>%
   mutate_if(is.numeric, .funs = list(perc = ~ as_perc(.)))

  col1 col2 col3 Total col2_perc col3_perc Total_perc
1    A   43  102   145     51.0%     21.0%      26.0%
2    B   23  230   253     27.0%     48.0%      45.0%
3    C   19  149   168     22.0%     31.0%      30.0%
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll take this one in note too!